# How to find and book different flights with different users concurrency using jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have one thread group.

1. Login api (Users A, B, C, D, E, F stored in CSV file)
2. Get flight api (body: depart time, depart airport, destination)
   My Request:

   ```
   {
       "DepartDate": "2018-08-22", 
       "DepartAirport": "PuDong", 
       "Destination": "Beijing" 
   }
   ```

Response format as below:

```
{  
    "DepartTime": "2018-08-22",
    "BookableTime": [
    {
        "DepartTime": "2018-08-22T03:30:00",
        "DepartAirport": "PuDong", 
        "Destination": "Beijing"
    },
    {
        "DepartTime": "2018-08-22T06:30:00",
        "DepartAirport": "PuDong", 
        "Destination": "Beijing"
    },
    {
        "DepartTime": "2018-08-22T07:30:00",
        "DepartAirport": "PuDong", 
        "Destination": "Beijing"
    },
     {
         "DepartTime": "2018-08-22T08:30:00",
         "DepartAirport": "PuDong", 
         "Destination": "Beijing"
     },
     {
         "DepartTime": "2018-08-22T09:30:00",
         "DepartAirport": "PuDong", 
         "Destination": "Beijing"
     },
     {
         "DepartTime": "2018-08-22T011:30:00",
         "DepartAirport": "PuDong", 
         "Destination": "Beijing"
     },
     {
         "DepartTime": "2018-08-22T013:30:00",
         "DepartAirport": "PuDong", 
         "Destination": "Beijing"
     }
 ] }
```

3. Book the flight api (I want different user book different flights)
   My Request:

   ```
   {   
       "DepartAirport": "PuDong", 
       "Destination": "Beijing", 
       "ClassType": "Economy", 
       "DepartTime": "${time}"  
   }
   ```

I want user A to book the first flight, user B to book the second flight, .... How to achieve that? I have to input all the flights in my CSV file currently, and I think that's not cool.

Comment: Are you testing an existing API or writing your own?

Comment: Yes, existing api. This is just an example.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) as a child of the request which returns departure times
2. Configure it as follows:

   [image: JMeter Extract JSON]

   this will result into the following [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

   ```
   time_1=2018-08-22T03:30:00
   time_2=2018-08-22T06:30:00
   time_3=2018-08-22T07:30:00
   time_4=2018-08-22T08:30:00
   time_5=2018-08-22T09:30:00
   time_6=2018-08-22T011:30:00
   time_7=2018-08-22T013:30:00
   ```
3. Now you need to use `time_1` for user 1, `time_2` for user 2, etc. You can achieve this using [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) and [__V()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) functions [combination](http://Here%E2%80%99s%20What%20to%20Do%20to%20Combine%20Multiple%20JMeter%20Variables) like:

   ```
   ${__V(time_${__threadNum})}
   ```

Comment: Seems I always get the first departTime for all users.

Comment: If you have > 1 thread in thread group - each one will be using new departTime